# How to read env environment with type .env file when deploy nestjs on cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, nestjs, google-cloud-run

I use nestjs and use cloud run google platform. My project have .env file with .env.dev(Dev) , stg (staging) and .env.prod (product). When i read document of google , cloud run when deploy support specific env file when using command :

```
gcloud run deploy  --env-vars-file .env.yaml FLAGS...
```

But it only support .env.yaml. Is it possible if I don't use .env.yaml format but use .env.stg or .env.prod format when I deploy in different environments. How do I specify the .env.stg or .env.prod environment variable when I do deploy ? Thanks you

Comment: be really careful saving enything in .env files, as it might be one of the most used vulnerabilities

Comment: @WalterVerhoeven but google cloud support deploy .env file ? Right

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't make it a good idea. please note that if you are on a shared server, you can read any environment variables. feel free to google it. We see 50+ different IP addresses attacking servers looking to exploit this every day and there are a ton of CVE's on the subject